# Focus ON/OFF in GUI.TextField

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, focus, enter

initially I thought I wouldn't have to post such a post,
because the topic seems quite simple. As you can see, he has surpassed me.

I have two logistical problems with the following code.
This is the piece of code (the rest doesn't matter to this one) which
is responsible for the cheat console.

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            HandleInput();
        }
    }

private void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0, y, Screen.width, consoleRectY), "");
        GUI.SetNextControlName("MyTextField");
        input = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10.0f, y + 15.0f, Screen.width - 20.0f, 60.0f), input, style);
        //GUI.FocusControl("MyTextField");
        //GUI.FocusControl(null);
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to combine something with `GUI.FocusControl`. But what is actually not working for me?

After clicking `KeyCode.BackQuote`, the console appears and to focus on it I have to click 'Tab',
enter the text, left-click outside the `TextField` and only then after I click 'Enter'
then the command takes place.

First of all, I would like the Focus to automatically turn on and at the time of typing like I click Enter then the (HandleInput ()) command is checked. I tried to use `GUI.FocusControl` but focus was on `TextField` all the time (it could not be turned off). As for typing this 'Enter'

I checked options with events, but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Well first things first, i dont recommend for you use OnGUI function to create any components at all it may be cause some issues for standalone build.  We dont have any idea about for "your console thing", but this isn't problem.

I'm not sure Unity editor key input event checker does check your keyboard inputs when focus at any input field, i suggest to you an alternate solution. But even it's not, for use code like this please check your "TextInputField" string value and make sure your inputField has multiline option.

```
 public void OnTextChange(string inputVal)
        {
            if (inputVal.EndsWith("\n"))
            {
                //do something
                HandleInput();
            }
        }
```

I hope this could solve your problem.